# How make the 'str +x' 'str+f' command relative

Tags: vim, filepath, relative-path

How can I change the start location of the 'str +x' 'str+f' command.

I mean my buffer is located in home/website/index.htm. But when I use the command he starts at home but I want him to start at my file location.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, `ctrl-x` `ctrl-f` looks for filenames that are in the folder where the vim session is located.

Use `:pwd` to check, where you are.

To change to the folder where the current file is located, type `:cd %:p:h` in normal mode.